# Unrecognized expression '$toObjectId' in mongoose aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my mongoose aggregation, I am getting error as `Unrecognized expression '$toObjectId'`. My MongoDB version is 4.2.5 and the mongoose version is 5.9.6. As per documentation, this operator is available in 4.x version and ideally should have worked.

```
  const trips = await Tickets.aggregate([
              {$match: {trip: Utils.strToObjectId(tripid) }},
              {$project: {_id:0,status:1, bookedBy:1,name:1,totalFare:1, seats:1, mode:1 }},
              {$group: {_id: {$toObjectId:"$bookedBy"}, bookings: {$push: {status: "$status", mode:"$mode", name: "$name", from: "$sourceCity", to: "$destinationCity", seats: "$seats" ,fare: "$totalFare", pnr: "$shortid" }}  }},
              {$lookup: {from:"users", localField:"bookedBy", foreignField:"_id",as:"user"}},
              ]);
```

In my case bookedBy get converted to string which is not matching in $lookup pipeline. so to resolve this I am trying to convert it to objectId.

Any help suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why it's failing !! What does this `Utils.strToObjectId(tripid)` return ?  Also I guess your `$lookup` doesn't work as you're retaining `bookedBy` field after `$group`, You can remove stage by stage & check where it's actually failing but I guess issue is not `$group`..

Comment: Please tell whats the value in the field `bookedBy`? The syntax `{ $group: { _id: { $toObjectId: "$bookedBy"}` is correct, using it with the `$group`.

Comment: @prasad_ in bookedBy I have objectId in string format. e.g. "5e841a3fa9f5d872777aa476"

Comment: @whoami It's simple function to convert string to mongoose ObjectId. below is the code 

const strToObjectId = (str)=>{
  return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(str);
}

Comment: bookedBy field contains objectId but it's in string format. If I apply $lookup then it's not matching because in mongodb it's ObjectId. That's why I am try to convert my input to ObjectId $toObjectId

Comment: Can you post couple of sample documents which are the result of (after) the pipeline stage `{$project: {_id:0,status:1, bookedBy:1,name:1,totalFare:1, seats:1, mode:1 }},`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and was wrestling with it for two days,
The solution for me was making sure my MongoDB is up to date,
 I was hosting mine on MLab.com which provided me with Mongo 3.6, whilst `$toObjectId` is available only from Mongo 4.0
I migrated my server to Mongo Atlas for free which provided me with the up to date version and everything ran smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with accessing objectId created by MongoDB,then why don't you create your own unique object Id and access wherever you want. By using this you don't need to worry about converting to object ID. For Example,

```
const MUUID = require('uuid-mongodb'); 
id: {
        type: 'object',
        unique: true,
        default: () => MUUID.v1().toString(),
    }
```

I am just a beginner. I am sorry if my answer is inconvenient or irrelevant. It's just an idea.Thank you